# Kubernetes: how to connect to service from outside the cluster?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxypass

I have created a service using this manual: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address-service/

The service has IP in this example (`10.32.0.16`, by `kubectl describe services example-service` command) and we can create proxy_pass rule: `proxy_pass http://10.32.0.16:8080;` in external (outside the cluster) nginx.

This IP is always different (it depends on number of services, etc..). How can I specify this service for my external nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- specify a [fixed IP for a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#choosing-your-own-ip-address)
- proxy to the [service DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/dns/)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, that I found very powerful, is to setup the nginx inside the cluster using the [official nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx).

Then you can have both load-balanced/HA nginx and have kubernetes automatically update its config from ingress rules.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) seems very popular for such cases.
It's taking over nginx ingress too...